# ETW EventSource Name at runtime

Tags: .net, manifest, system.diagnostics, etw, etw-eventsource

I would like to know, if we can set EventSource Name during runtime.

```
[EventSource(Name = "Test-SourceLogger")]
public sealed class EventSourceLogger : EventSource
```

I have multiple applications who wants to log to different EventSources. If this can be made configurable i can reuse the component for EventViewer.

Additional information on EventSourceAttribute

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public sealed class EventSourceAttribute : Attribute
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok, there is a `Name` property. Try to set this and see if this works.

Comment: Name Property is set during compile time(Hard coded), is there any way i can assess this property during runtime and change this.

Comment: it has a public set/get, so give it a try. If this doesn't work you're SOL.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass event source name through constructor of the instance of your EventSource. Every new instance can have different event source name. Just do not use singleton pattern.

Comment: Take a look on implementation of EtwQueueEventSource on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43232306/etw-eventsource-in-a-common-component/43375037#43375037)